# How to sort an ArrayList of Strings with seasons and years?

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an unsorted ArrayList of Strings of seasons and years like the following:

```
["Summer 2020", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Winter 2018", "Summer 2018", "Winter 2020", "Spring 2018"]
```

The correct sorting of this list is the following:

```
["Winter 2018", "Spring 2018", "Summer 2018", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Winter 2020", "Summer 2020"]
```

How can I achieve this order? The order of seasons in a year is like Winter 2021, Spring 2021, Summer 2021, Autumn 2021, and all the seasons for every year will not necessarily exist in the list.

Comment: Q: How do I sort an ArrayList of seasons and years like this?  A: It doesn't look like your example is even legal Java.  I'm guessing your ArrayList actually consists of "String" elements.  IN ANY CASE: 1) Just write a custom [Comparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/).  2) Your comparator will parse the two elements you're comparing for "Season" and "year", then return -1, 0 or 1 as appropriate.  Easy peasy.  Look at the link I cited for examples.

Comment: I would add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) to use its [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class instead of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to implement a custom `Comparator` that sorts by the year first and then by the seasons. An `enum` can be used to specify the order of the seasons easily.

```
private static class SeasonComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    
    private enum Season {
        WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] arr1 = s1.split(" ");
        String[] arr2 = s2.split(" ");
        
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(arr1[1]);
        int year2 = Integer.parseInt(arr2[1]);
        
        if (year1 != year2) {
            return year1 - year2;
        } else {
            Season season1 = Season.valueOf(arr1[0].toUpperCase());
            Season season2 = Season.valueOf(arr2[0].toUpperCase());
            return season1.ordinal() - season2.ordinal();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> seasons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Summer 2020", "Autumn 2018",
            "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Winter 2018", "Summer 2018", "Winter 2020", "Spring 2018"));

    System.out.println("Unordered list:");
    System.out.println(seasons);
    
    seasons.sort(new SeasonComparator());
    
    System.out.println("Sorted list:");
    System.out.println(seasons);
}
```

**Output**

```
Unordered list:
[Summer 2020, Autumn 2018, Spring 2019, Autumn 2019, Winter 2018, Summer 2018, Winter 2020, Spring 2018]

Sorted list:
[Winter 2018, Spring 2018, Summer 2018, Autumn 2018, Spring 2019, Autumn 2019, Winter 2020, Summer 2020]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write own [`comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for such strings. I suggest you to use `arrow` function for it. Also, to sort seasons you need to give them some priority, I would use `Map<String, Integer>` for it.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> seasonsPriority = new HashMap<>();
    seasonsPriority.put("Winter", 1);
    seasonsPriority.put("Spring", 2);
    seasonsPriority.put("Summer", 3);
    seasonsPriority.put("Autumn", 4);

    ArrayList<String> seasons = new ArrayList<>();
    seasons.add("Summer 2020");
    seasons.add("Autumn 2018");
    seasons.add("Spring 2019");
    seasons.add("Autumn 2019");
    seasons.add("Winter 2018");
    seasons.add("Summer 2018");
    seasons.add("Winter 2020");
    seasons.add("Spring 2018");


    seasons.sort((x, y) -> {
        int firstYear = Integer.parseInt(x.split(" ")[1]);
        int secondYear = Integer.parseInt(y.split(" ")[1]);

        if(firstYear < secondYear) {
            return -1;
        }

        if(firstYear > secondYear) {
            return 1;
        }

        String firstSeason = x.split(" ")[0];
        String secondSeason = y.split(" ")[0];

        return Integer.compare(seasonsPriority.get(firstSeason), seasonsPriority.get(secondSeason));
    });

    System.out.println(seasons);
}
```

Output:

```
[Winter 2018, Spring 2018, Summer 2018, Autumn 2018, Spring 2019, Autumn 2019, Winter 2020, Summer 2020]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider writing a custom Comparator to perform sorting with custom logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Summer 2020", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Winter 2018", "Summer 2018", "Winter 2020", "Spring 2018");

    List<String> listOfSeasonsInAscendingOrder = Arrays.asList("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn");

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String firstStringSplit[] = o1.split(" ");
            String season1 = firstStringSplit[0];
            int year1 = Integer.valueOf(firstStringSplit[1]);

            String secondStringSplit[] = o2.split(" ");
            String season2 = secondStringSplit[0];
            int year2 = Integer.valueOf(secondStringSplit[1]);

            if (year1 != year2) {
                return year1 < year2 ? -1 : 1;
            }

            int indexOfSeason1 = listOfSeasonsInAscendingOrder.indexOf(season1);
            int indexOfSeason2 = listOfSeasonsInAscendingOrder.indexOf(season2);

            return indexOfSeason1 == indexOfSeason2 ? 0 : indexOfSeason1 < indexOfSeason2 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Sorted List = " + list);
}
```

Output of the above code is :-

```
Sorted List = [Winter 2018, Spring 2018, Summer 2018, Autumn 2018, Spring 2019, Autumn 2019, Winter 2020, Summer 2020]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
static final Map<String, Integer> SEASON_ORDER = Map.of(
    "Winter", 0, "Spring", 1, "Summer", 2, "Autumn", 3);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        "Summer 2020", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019",
        "Winter 2018", "Summer 2018", "Winter 2020", "Spring 2018"));
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> {
        String[] a = s.split("\\s+");
        return a[1] + SEASON_ORDER.get(a[0]);
    }));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

output:

```
[Winter 2018, Spring 2018, Summer 2018, Autumn 2018, Spring 2019, Autumn 2019, Winter 2020, Summer 2020]
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers all perform the string splitting and parsing within the comparator function.  This works perfectly fine, but might cause performance issues at scale - splitting and parsing can be relatively expensive operations, and when sorting a comparator will need to check each element on average more than once.  It might improve performance to have the comparator calculate a code for each element that naturally sorts correctly, and remember the codes using a map, to avoid having to perform these operations more than once per element:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Summer 2020", "Autumn 2018", "Spring 2019", "Autumn 2019", "Winter 2018", "Summer 2018", "Winter 2020", "Spring 2018");
        list.sort(new SeasonYearComparator());
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private enum Season {
        Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn;
    }

    private static class SeasonYearComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        private final Map<String, String> codes = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String code1 = codes.computeIfAbsent(s1, this::computeCode);
            String code2 = codes.computeIfAbsent(s2, this::computeCode);
            return code1.compareTo(code2);
        }

        private String computeCode(String seasonYear) {
            String[] parts = seasonYear.split(" ");
            return parts[1] + Season.valueOf(parts[0]).ordinal();
        }
    }
}
```